# CVSS score for no-input validation

Tags: penetration-test, validation, cvss

During a security assesment I found that an application wrote JavaScript from input fields directly in the database. The application it self had good output sanitization so no XSS was possible in that application. A different application that used the same data didn't have good output sanitization and had a XSS vulnerability, which has been fixed since then.

So wat I have now is a finding that input data is not properly validated, which might pose problems for applications that do not sanitize output well but not in the current application. What CVSS score would I put on that? I cannot well make it a high vulnerability because it is impossible to exploit now. But in the future it could pose problems and I do want it fixed in the context of "defense in depth"

**Question: What would the CVSS score be for a non-exploitable input validation vulnerability?**

Comment: In the majority of cases you should *only* sanitize the output. That is, it's absolutely fine to store a literal `<` in the database if you turn it into a `&lt;` before output. If you escape and sanitize at multiple places you might even introduce new vulnerabilities. It's a bad idea to store sanitized data "just in case someone forgets filtering the output".

Comment: Yes I do understand that, but I also think that the validity of the data is the explicit responsibility of the system that first receives the data from end-users. This is especially true when this data is then used in internal systems and the data has a clear purpose. In this instance it is about names and birthdates so data with clear text and numbers only restrictions.

Comment: Yes, wrt. input validation of birthdates, etc. you're absolutely right. I was more concerned about, say, a comment box that has to prevent users from adding HTML tags. (Here it would be okay to store the literal comment text and sanitize when printing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The score would be 0.0. Since there is no immediate impact, the confidentiality, integrity and availability would be set to *none*, which would make the score 0.0.

Also, it is not necessarily a security issue that user input is saved as-is in the database. The important thing is that it is correctly encoded on output.

Comment: So CVSS would only be calculated on immediate impact and not on possible impact? (and I do not agree with your last statement but I think we could have hours of discussion on that so we'll leave it :P)